# Python: Printing nested dictionary in .csv file, how to remove [] and '

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'Bob': {'Car': ['a = 1.10', 'b = 1.50'], 'House': ['c = 1.20'], 'Hp': 'true', 'Wife': 'false'},
     'Sam': {'Car': ['d = 1.40'], 'House': ['c = 1.60'], 'Hp': 'true', 'Wife': 'true'}}
```

I want to print it in a table in .csv file.

My desired output (when opened in Excel):

```
Name Hp    Wife  Car                 House
Bob  true  false a = 1.10, b = 1.50  c = 1.20
Sam  true  true  d = 1.60            c = 1.40
```

My code so far:

```
header = ['Name', 'Hp', 'Wife', 'Car', 'House']
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        row.update(val)
        w.writerow(row)
```

But the output that I got is this (when opened in Excel):

```
Name Hp    Wife  Car                         House
Bob  true  false "['a = 1.10', 'b = 1.50']"  ['c = 1.20']
Sam  true  true  ['d = 1.60']                ['c = 1.40']
```

Is there a way to remove the `[]` and `'` besides using the find and replace function in Excel?

Comment: Use `', '.join(row)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` the items in the list and update the dictionary. The joining should be done with a semi-colon, to avoid moving items to the next column or having them wrapped with `" "`:

```
header = ['Name', 'Hp', 'Wife', 'Car', 'House']
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        row.update(val)
        row['Car'] = '; '.join(row['Car'])  # here
        row['House'] = '; '.join(row['House']) # here
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I got `"a = 1.10, b = 1.50"` for Bob's Car, how to remove `"`?

Comment: @TanWenYan I updated my answer to join on a semi-colon for `row['Car']`. Joining on a comma could easily make `b` move to the next column, so the `csv` module wraps both `a` and `b` in a `""`. Using a `;` clears the `""`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it by using `str.join()` to join the items in the nested lists. The nested lists are detected using `isinstance()`. If you do not specify a delimiter when creating the csv writer, it will default to comma so this code:

```
import csv

d = {'Bob': {'Car': ['a = 1.10', 'b = 1.50'],
         'House': ['c = 1.20'],
         'Hp': 'true',
         'Wife': 'false'},
     'Sam': {'Car': ['d = 1.40'],
         'House': ['c = 1.60'],
         'Hp': 'true',
         'Wife': 'true'}}

header = ['Name', 'Hp', 'Wife', 'Car', 'House']

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for name in sorted(d):
        values_dict = {k: v if not isinstance(v, list) else ', '.join(v)
                            for k,v in d[name].items()}
        w.writerow(dict(Name=name, **values_dict))
```

will output

```
Name,Hp,Wife,Car,House
Bob,true,false,"a = 1.10, b = 1.50",c = 1.20
Sam,true,true,d = 1.40,c = 1.60
```

to the csv file. Notice that there are embedded quotes in the output. This is so that Excel will not interpret the inner `,` as a delimiter, and Excel will not display the quotes when the file is loaded. It's fine to leave it there.

If you don't like that you can change the csv delimiter to a space for example:

```
w = csv.DictWriter(f, header, delimiter=' ')
```

Or you could use a different delimiter when joining the items in the nested lists.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I would like to ask will this work if Sam doesn't have `'House': ['c = 1.60']` at all, meaning that I would like the code to check for each key (`Bob`, `Sam`, etc) whether they have `House` or `Car` first.

Comment: and the last line, `w.writerow(dict(Name=name, **values_dict))`, can I write it as `w.writerow(dict(values_dict, Name = name))`?

Comment: @TanWenYan: You can try it out to see if it works :) For the second one, yes!.... you don't need to, and shouldn't, unpack the dictionary as I showed (not sure why I thought that was necessary). As for the first issue, if a key is missing from the dict passed to `writerows()`, the value for that field will be empty in the output CSV file. So the code does handle missing items in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['a = 1.10', 'b = 1.50']
print x
print str(x).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')
```